# Spring Actuator Changes Upgrading From Spring Boot 2.4.3 to 2.6.2

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

We have a Spring Boot web application developed with Spring Boot 2.4.3 and deploys Spring Actuator. I am investigating upgrading to Spring Boot 2.6.2 and have the majority of the issues working. I removed spring actuator starter from the project and war file and it deploys and runs fine. We are running using Java 11 and Wildfly 18.

If I add the spring actuator starter back into to the project pom file and war file pom files, it shows the following warning during deployment:

```
16:44:28,063 WARN  [org.jboss.modules.define] (Thread-115) Failed to define class io.micrometer.core.instrument.binder.jersey.server.MetricsApplicationEventListener in Module "deployment.test.war" from Service Module Loader: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed to link io/micrometer/core/instrument/binder/jersey/server/MetricsApplicationEventListener (Module "deployment.test.war" from Service Module Loader): org/glassfish/jersey/server/monitoring/ApplicationEventListener
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1016)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1095)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:424)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:555)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:339)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:126)
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:731)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:247)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:410)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:116)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:398)
    at deployment.test.war//org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.FilteringSpringBootCondition.resolve(FilteringSpringBootCondition.java:108)
    at deployment.test.war//org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.FilteringSpringBootCondition$ClassNameFilter.isPresent(FilteringSpringBootCondition.java:140)
    at deployment.test.war//org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.FilteringSpringBootCondition$ClassNameFilter$2.matches(FilteringSpringBootCondition.java:128)
    at deployment.test.war//org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnClassCondition$StandardOutcomesResolver.getOutcome(OnClassCondition.java:227)
    at deployment.test.war//org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnClassCondition$StandardOutcomesResolver.getOutcome(OnClassCondition.java:214)
    at deployment.test.war//org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnClassCondition$StandardOutcomesResolver.getOutcomes(OnClassCondition.java:201)
    at deployment.test.war//org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnClassCondition$StandardOutcomesResolver.resolveOutcomes(OnClassCondition.java:190)
    at deployment.test.war//org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnClassCondition$ThreadedOutcomesResolver.lambda$new$0(OnClassCondition.java:150)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

I went down the path of trying to add jar files to the project for the missing class, but the problem adds to another missing class file. I could not find any major changes in Spring Actuator between Spring Boot versions 2.4.2 and 2.6.2 that would cause this problem.

Does anyone have any insight into changes in Spring Boot that might cause the deployment issue?

Comment: I suggest you do a two-step migration. First, migrate to Spring Boot 2.5 (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.5-Release-Notes) and after having it working migrate to Spring Boot 2.6.2 (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.6-Release-Notes).

Comment: In the release notes of Spring Boot 2.5, you can read: "Actuator will now generate Micrometer metrics for Spring Data repositories. By default, metrics are named spring.data.repository.invocations." (you can read more at https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.5.0/reference/html/actuator.html#actuator.metrics.supported.spring-data-repository).

Comment: I have the same issue. Any progress on this one?

Comment: What is the problem caused by this? I get that you’re seeing warnings in the logs but is there a functional bug caused by it?

Comment: Spring Boot's checking to see if `io.micrometer.core.instrument.binder.jersey.server.MetricsApplicationEventListener` is on the classpath. This check is causing Wildfly to, unnecessarily IMO, log a warning. That should be benign, however, as Boot should then continue to bootstrap that rest of Actuator. If that's not happening, there may have been failures shown later in the log that show the reason.

Comment: The only issue is the warning log statement. It tends to make people concerned. I have seen no functionality issues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To disable the JerseyServerMetricsAutoConfiguration class in a Spring Boot application, you can use the @SpringBootApplication annotation with the exclude attribute. Here's an example:

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = JerseyServerMetricsAutoConfiguration.class)
public class MyApplication {
    // ...
}
```

In the example above, the JerseyServerMetricsAutoConfiguration class is excluded from the application configuration by specifying it in the exclude attribute of the @SpringBootApplication annotation.

Alternatively, you can use the @EnableAutoConfiguration annotation with the exclude attribute to achieve the same result:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = JerseyServerMetricsAutoConfiguration.class)
public class MyApplication {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in the impossibility of finding the dependency of "org/glassfish/jersey/server/monitoring/ApplicationEventListener" at deployment.

A possible solution is to include in the war the dependency

```
<dependency> 
<groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
<artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId> 
</dependency>
```